# AWS iOS/Android SDK size issues

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk

I am working on a library right now and I have a need to integrate AWS SDK in there.
I am using just two AWS SQS services in my library -

1. Create Queue
2. Send Message ( upload some data )

The overall size impact of AWS SDK(iOS and Android) on my library is huge( more than 50% in both platforms ). To convince partners it is a prime requirement that I reduce the size of my library.

My questions are-

- Is there anything already existing that I can use directly for creating queues and uploading data?
- How can I implement something like a lightweight version of AWS SDK by myself for this use case?

NOTE: I am noob to AWS stuff.

Comment: All AWS API's are based on REST. All you need to do is make an request to the endpoint for the service you are using. The SDK's do provide some convenience and abstraction to the REST services but they are not critical to use.

Comment: what else are you doing from your app? You could (and probably should) do this on the server-side. Otherwise you are distributing *your* keys in your app.

Comment: We have the keys secure by linking it with our web-service endpoint and encodings, so security is not an issue. My concern is how do I implement the REST API's. I saw the documentation and it looks a bit complex, it would be really helpful if someone can break things down and explain it in simple words.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to consume the AWS SDK for iOS: through CocoaPods and `AWSiOSSDKv2.framework`. If you are using CocoaPods, you can use the following `Podfile` to import only the code necessary for Amazon SQS:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

pod 'AWSiOSSDKv2/SQS'
```

If you are using `AWSiOSSDKv2.framework`, you can remove the `-ObjC` flag from **Other Linker Flags** in your **Build Settings**. Xcode is smart enough to bring only the object files used in your app from the framework, and the binary size impact to the final app is minimal. If you have other frameworks that require the `-ObjC` flag, you can use `-force_load` on those frameworks instead of `-ObjC`.

On the Android side, we are continuously working on reducing the jar sizes, so please make sure you grab the latest version of the SDK. The size of the AWS Mobile SDK for Android 2.1.8 (Amazon SQS only) is:

- `aws-android-sdk-2.1.8-core.jar`: 2MB
- `aws-android-sdk-2.1.8-sqs.jar`: 180KB

We also ship our Proguard setting recommendations with the SDK. Please see `Proguard.html` on how to reduce the app binary size with Proguard.

As a side note, please make sure you have thoroughly reviewed the permissions for creating queues from the mobile device. In general, we do not recommend creating queues from mobile devices because any credentials on mobile devices can be extracted and abused by malicious users. Only exception to this is when you "trust" all of your end users (such as when you are writing an enterprise applications for employees).

Comment: This size is too much for my requirement and in future we will also need to use s3 services so I don't think this will work. Keeping our library small is really important for us.

Comment: How do I use aws rest apis for to SendMessage of the order of 256KB?

Answer (score 0):

[aws-lightweight-client-java](https://github.com/davidmoten/aws-lightweight-client-java) is less than 60K (standalone, no dependencies). This is how you perform those tasks:

```
Client sqs = Client
  .sqs()
  .regionName("ap-southeast-2")
  .accessKey(accessKey)
  .secretKey(secretKey)
  .build();

String queueUrl = 
  sqs.query("Action", "CreateQueue") 
    .query("QueueName", queueName) 
    .responseAsXml()
    .content("CreateQueueResult", "QueueUrl");

sqs.url(queueUrl) 
    .query("Action", "SendMessage") 
    .query("MessageBody", "hi there") 
    .execute();
```